# Are most of today’s web applications (and web service applications) being written using ORM?

Tags: orm

I know there are plenty of threads on when you should/shouldn’t use ORM. But at my level of “expertise” I’m far from qualified to be able to tell whether or not my app would be better off with or without ORM. And I don’t want to wait till I’m proficient enough to figure out whether I should learn ORM or not.

So could you tell me whether or not most of today’s web service apps (and most of web apps in general) are being written using ORM?

PS - I'm learning WCF and Asp.Net Web forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess a lot of webapps (yes, probably most of them) use some orm persistence layer these days, provided they use a relational database. That goes for java (hibernate, jpa), .net, Python, groovy/grails and Rails (ActiveRecord by default).

There are also more and more orm solutions appearing for non-relational data stores.

It certainly depends on the language and application framework you are using, if any.